# Using provider package StreamProvider with declarative UI

Tags: flutter, state-management

I've been trying to wrap my head around data flow and state management in flutter particularly using the provider package. I tried querying from firestore using `Future` but turns out that doesn't fully utilise the capabilities of firestore since `Future`s only expect one value.
So I switched to using `Stream`s instead, and using `StreamProvider` to get the data to my widgets. Problem is I can't figure out at what point/how to tell the UI to rebuild. Sometimes the stream has data, sometimes it doesn't and I can't really tell what's going on during those times. Say I wanted to show a circular progress bar when the view is busy, how do I achieve that when using `StreamProvider`. Does it even make sense to do that?

So with the [filledstacks](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-architecture-provider-implementation-guide-d33133a9a4e8) approach, one is able to switch model state between Busy and Idle, when making a network call using futures. For instance when we call a `getPosts` method, we first set the state to Busy so the UI can react and probably show a loading indicator. However we can set the state back to Idle once data has been received async. A `Stream` on the other hand, at least from my understanding, is just a pipe that's constantly passing data and I can't come up with a way to achieve the Busy/Idle state or even to tell if this `Stream` has new data/any data. Any ideas?

This is part of my `database_service.dart` that should return a stream of data from firestore.

```dart
Stream<List<Expense>> getExpenses(int month, int year) {
    var ref = _db
        .collection("userData")
        .document(fireUser.uid)
        .collection("expenses")
        .where("month", isEqualTo: month)
        .where("year", isEqualTo: year)
        .orderBy("date", descending: true);

    return ref.snapshots().map((list) =>
        list.documents.map((snap) => Expense.fromFirestore(snap)).toList());
  }
```

This is part of my `expenses.dart` view file that uses `StreamProvider`.

```dart
class ExpensesPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExpensesPageState createState() => _ExpensesPageState();
}
class _ExpensesPageState extends State<ExpensesPage> {
  int _month;
  int _year;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _month = DateTime.now().month;
    _year = DateTime.now().year;
  }

    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<List<Expense>>.value(
      stream: locator<ExpensesProvider>().getMonthExpenses(_month, _year),
      initialData: [],
      child: StreamProvider<List<Category>>.value(
        stream: locator<ExpensesProvider>().getCategories(),
        initialData: [],
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                InkWell(
                  child: DateHeader("$_month $_year"),
                  onTap: () => _selectDate(),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ExpenseList(
                    month: _month,
                    year: _year,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

and `expense_list.dart` with the `ExpenseList` widget that consumes data from the `StreamProvider`.

```dart
class ExpenseList extends StatelessWidget {
  final _dateFormat = DateFormat.yMMMEd();
  final _dbService = locator<DatabaseService>();
  final int month;
  final int year;

  ExpenseList({@required this.month, @required this.year});

  String getMonthName(int month) {
    return _dbService.monthNames[month - 1];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var expenses = Provider.of<List<Expense>>(context);
    var categories = Provider.of<List<Category>>(context);
    return expenses.length < 1
        ? Center(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Text(
                "You do not have any expenses for ${getMonthName(month)}, $year",
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          )
        : ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              var cat = categories.firstWhere(
                (category) => category.id == expenses[index].category,
                orElse: () => Category.initial(),
              );
              var sub = cat.subs[expenses[index].subcategory];
              var amount = expenses[index].amount;
              var date = expenses[index].date;
              return ExpenseCard(
                  expenseCategory: cat.name,
                  expenseSubCategory: sub,
                  expenseAmount: amount,
                  expenseDate: _dateFormat.format(date),
                  cardColor: Theme.of(context).cardColor);
            },
            itemCount: expenses.length,
          );
  }
}
```

My UI is constantly at this

[image: stage]

,even though I expect it to update with the data from the `StreamProvider`.

Comment: Is removing `initialData` and treating `null` as the loading state a good enough solution for you?

Comment: You'd typically want to use `rxdart`, with a `switchMap`. But from your code, I don't understand when you'd  want to go to the loading state again

Comment: I'm more concerned about the fact that the stream should have brought in data from firestore so that the app's state goes beyond `initialData`. However it's stuck at `initialData` and the stream doesn't seem to emit more values

Comment: Hey @Arden did you find a solution for this? I'm experiencing the same problem..

Comment: You can try isolating the issue first to determine if the behavior was caused by the Firestore query or by your implementation of StreamProvider. Could you provide a [minimal repro](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the issue so this can be reproducible locally?